# jQueryUI autocomplete updated textbox field does not response correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a ASP.NET structure like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtArea" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and try to use jQueryUI autocomplete on both fields, here is the javascript that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= txtArea.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        search: function(event, ui) { alert($('#<%= txtCity.ClientID%>').val()); },
        source: "handlers/AreaLocator.ashx?loc=" + $('#<%= txtCity.ClientID%>').val(),
        select: function(event, ui) { alert('aa'); }
    });

    $('#<%= txtCity.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: "handlers/CityLocator.ashx",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#<%= txtCity.ClientID%>').val(ui.item.city);
        }
    });

});
```

but in my code behind in AreaLocator.ashx I can't get the value for loc querystring. Amazingly search event of txtArea autocomplete displays me the value selected in txtCity autocomplete. Anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong? Order of both auto complete doesn't make any difference and there is no cross browser problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That won't quite work, because your selector in the `source` option will only be evaluated once. You have two options:

1. Rename `loc` to `term` on the server. In that case, your JavaScript would just be:

   ```javascript
   $('#<%= txtArea.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
       minLength: 3,
       search: function(event, ui) { alert($('#<%= txtArea.ClientID%>').val()); },
       source: "handlers/AreaLocator.ashx",
       select: function(event, ui) { alert('aa'); }
   });
   ```

   Then, on the server, you would look for `term` instead of `loc`. Autocomplete will adds the parameter `term` to the URL.
2. If that's not possible or you'd rather not change the server-side code, you can make your AJAX request yourself by passing a function to the `source` option:

   ```javascript
   $('#<%= txtArea.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
       minLength: 3,
       search: function(event, ui) { alert($('#<%= txtArea.ClientID%>').val()); },
       source: function (request, response) {
           $.ajax({
               url: "handlers/AreaLocator.ashx",
               data: { loc: $('#<%= txtCity.ClientID%>').val() },
               dataType: "json",
               success: response,
               error: function() {
                   response([]);
               }
           });                
       }
       select: function(event, ui) { alert('aa'); }
   });
   ```

As for your other problem:

> Amazingly search event of txtArea autocomplete displays me the value selected in txtCity autocomplete.

This is simply because you have a typo in the `txtArea` autocomplete's search event.

```javascript
alert($('#<%= txtCity.ClientID%>').val());
```

should be:

```javascript
alert($('#<%= txtArea.ClientID%>').val());
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply, but you changed my code a little, you use txtArea in search event of txtArea autocomplete. In fact txtArea is dependent on txtCity field, so I must have to sent city name to AreaLocator.ashx. I was amazed because search event of txtArea autocomplete populates txtCity, on the other hand right after search event, source event can not attach txtCity value to URL.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. I updated my answer so that the autocomplete for `txtArea` uses the value from `txtCity`. Is this what you need?

Comment: I have tried ajax with lots of variations, but no luck. JSON created by my code behind [{"area":87,"label":"Gul Bahar"}, {"area":88,"label":"Gulistan-e-Jauhar"}], is not populate. I checked it by (http://jsonlint.com/) and it is valid .

Comment: No Andrew, not at all. Most interesting thing is, in one of my page I am using it like this, source: "handlers/SearchAutoComplete.ashx?loc=" + $('#hfLocation').val(), where hfLocation is a hidden field and is updated on document.ready with the following code: $('#hfLocation').val(some_geoip_city_method_from_external_server())

Comment: That's weird. I'm not sure how else to debug... Can you reproduce the problem with a local data source instead of using AJAX?

Comment: So, now as a hopeless case I am closing this question as UNSOLVED. For anyone who will read this thread, i would like to summarize my problem: I need to create a cascading style autocomplete where area is based on city input. Thanks for all who share.